# Sencha touch 2 user login example

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch and trying make an app where user has to login to be able to use the app. Furthermore, I have created restful api for user authentication which responses user in json format if the authentication is correct. The api url for the user authentication looks like this: `http://api-url/user/$username/$password.`

My Login View:

```
Ext.define('NCAPP.view.tablet.LoginForm', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype:'loginForm',
id:'loginForm',

requires:[
    'Ext.form.Panel',
    'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    'Ext.field.Password',
    'Ext.Img',
    'Ext.field.Toggle'
],
config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'image',
            src:'resources/img/netcenter_logo.png',
            height: 100
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'NCAPP LOGIN:',
            items: [

                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    id:'fldUsername',
                    name:'username',
                    placeHolder: 'Username'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'passwordfield',
                    id:'fldPassword',
                    name:'passowrd',
                    placeHolder: 'Password'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            id: 'btnLogin',
            text: 'Login'

        }
    ]
}
```

});

And I also have User Model:

```
Ext.define('NCAPP.model.User', {
extend:'Ext.data.Model',

config:{
    fields:[
        { name:'id', type: 'int'},

        { name: 'username', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'netshop_id', type:'int'},
        { name: 'firstname', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'lastname', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'address', type: 'string'},
         { name:'password', type:'string'},
        ]


}
```

});

And My Login controller:

```
Ext.define('NCAPP.controller.tablet.LoginController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',    
config: {
    refs: {   
        loginForm:'loginForm'
    },
    control: {
        '#btnLogin':{
            tap:'onLoginButtonTap'
        }            
    }
},
onLoginButtonTap:function(){

},
init:function(application){

}
```

});

As I have mentioned earlier, my api is completely restful. I think I can't use ajax proxy and i have to use rest proxy. My big question is how can pass the username and password to restful api?

Can any body help me with this (preferably with example)?

Comment: Unrelated to the answer to your question, but you should **really** not be sending the username and password directly over the URL using plain HTTP. While sending it over HTTP at all isn't safe, sending it in the URL makes it even easier for some random person to steal user credentials.

Comment: Can you please let me know which is the best way to authenticate user if i have restful api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few precisions your RESTful API. As you are trying to authenticate a user, the login and password, even if encrypted/hashed should **never** be in your URL. Instead, prefer a POST request with the url api-url/user/ and a POST message (json for exemple) containing your username and password.

For the ajax request, in your controller, you should do something like (assuming everything works properly):

```
Ext.define('NCAPP.controller.tablet.LoginController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',    
    config: {
        refs: {   
            loginForm:'loginForm'
        },
        control: {
            '#btnLogin':{
                tap:'onLoginButtonTap'
            }            
        }
    },
    onLoginButtonTap:function(){
        var values = this.getLoginForm().getValues();
        var jsonToPost = {};
        jsonToPost.user = values.username;
        jsonToPost.passwd = values.password;
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'your-url/user',
            method: 'POST',
            params: jsonToPost,
            success: function(response) {
                // Server send a 200 code response. it means it understood the request and was able to deal with it
                // you should check whether or not it is a success. Your answer JSON should contain this information
            },
            failure: function(response) {
                // any other response than a 200
            }
        });
    },
    init:function(application){

    }    
});
```

The code **has been** tested.

Comment: Hi Pierre, Thanks for your answer. I am wondering that how can I retrieve the username and password in the API if I have post request. (I should verify the username and password against database in api) I am sorry to say that I am quite new in sencha touch and API developing.

Comment: Let me edit the answer with more details. The REST example that I gave you is correct though, just like jprofitt said in his other response. But you should consider at least a SSL connection for more security. But this is the topic for another question!

Comment: I will implement SSL connection in the production environment. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question. You mention retrieving the user and password in the API and test it in the database. these two things are different. Sencha touch is on the client side, and then my answer is correct. Testing against the database in on the server side, and an answer to this will mainly depend on the language you are using. Java? C#? PHP? If it's the latter, you can use something like $_POST['username']; to get your parameters. even if the auth failed, you should send back a 200 response, where 40x are reserved for other failures

Comment: On the other hand, I am trying to authenticate user using model/store/proxy. is this correct way for user authentication?

Comment: Ok so I've slightly edited my answer.
check http://www.recessframework.org/page/routing-in-recess-screencast and they show down on the page how to check for POST requests..
If you will have multiple user, then yes a store with a model is definitely the way to go. Otherwise that might be heavy for your app to create all this for juste one user and you should store it in your app delegate or something..
Please upvote the answer or accept if it was a good for you.

Comment: Hi Pierre! I am trying to make the app in such a way that after user login, user will see main menu with different icons (lets say 3x3 icons). When user tap on the icon, different module will be loaded for example order module or invoice module etc. My question is which component can i use for main menu like container component or dataview and which component for icons like button or image? thanks

Comment: Really it's up to you here. Depends really on the level of modularity you want to have. If this is just these three icons, I would use a simple container and set it's html. Then you can use your CSS (sass is great by the way) to actually show your icons.
if you want to show text as well, that might vary, you can use a list, or a dataview and use the itemTpl.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I must show with text as well, So dataview will be best solution, right?

Comment: depend if the text will vary and if you need the template or not. XTemplate are extremely powerful, but if it's just plain HTML, with no modifications, then just use a container..

Comment: I have the picture of sample app. I would like to make the main menu like that. If it is possible to have your email address, I can send the picture to you and you can give me the accurate solution.

Comment: Hi Pierre! Can you please send me email address once? I was free on last three days, so I couldn't send you email. I am sorry for that...